# Top command failing in my embedded device

Tags: embedded-linux, procps

When I fire the `top` command for my board it says `'vt102': unknown terminal type.` I cant seem to figure out why it is happening so I have also loaded the library files from my PC into the board.The procps was built using my own cross-sompiled gcc which went quite well. Does anyone know what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I instead hacked into the code and commented the //#include asm/page.h and good gracious it worked.
If anyone need help on the issue leave a post.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem lies in the TERM environment variable.

Try to do

```
export TERM=linux
```

and to relaunch top